# Pandas: Edits on a dataframe are auto transferred onto an older one for reference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

The following code is just for demo.

```
import pandas as pd
Df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Col0': [1,2,3], 'Col1': [4,5,6]})
Df1 = Df0
Df1.attr = 'test'
```

Why does `Df0` also have the attribute `'test'` added on `Df1`, i.e. if I run `Df0.attr` I would also get `'test'`?

This phenomenon is confusing to me, but I don't know why and whether it is normal for programmers in the Python community (I'm more familiar with R programming and from the stat community). Is this common for Python or just for Pandas? How can I avoid this phenomenon? My IDE is Spyder btw.

Comment: **Df1** is not a new instance. It's just new reference address of **Df0**. Try `Df1 = Df0.copy()`

Comment: Df1 = DF0.copy(), creates a new instance, instead of a reference

Comment: `Df0.copy()` will return new instance.

Comment: Thanks @Lazyer @Naveed Another related question: Why the edit ```Df1=0``` not auto transferred onto ```Df0```?

Comment: **0** is a constant. `Df1=0` disconnect the reference address and assign new data without replacing the referenced data. I think it's pretty deep to discuss in the comments.

Comment: Saying `Df1 = Df0` binds Df1 to the same object Df0 refers to.  Changing one changes the other.  Saying `Df1 = xxx` breaks the connection and binds Df1 to a different object.  The distinction between names and objects (which do not have names) is CRITICAL to writing Python code.  It needs to be understood.

Comment: Thank you @Lazyer From now on, I'll be fine with using ```copy()``` instead when I do pandas dataframe manipulations. Just interested to know if ```Df0``` is **not** a pandas dataframe and I want to do the same thing like ```Df1=Df0```, edit ```Df1``` and leave ```Df0``` unchanged, then what is the basic principle?

Comment: Change together is style of the python I think. Not only dataframe, list and dict and every variable except for constant is working as bellows too.